# retrieving using linq query and entityframework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have table structure like below

Employee Table

```
ID   Name
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E
```

Employee allocation table

```
Alocationid    ID   Date
1              2    26/6/2013
2              2    25/6/2013
3              1    25/6/2013
4              1    24/6/2013
5              3    24/6/2013
6              4    26/6/2013
```

Now i need to get the available employees for a particular date.for example if i need available employees for 25/6/2013 then the result would be like below:-

```
ID  Name
1   A
3   C
4   D
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: @subash next time please specify language and post some code which you already have

Comment: @subash I don't understand why result is A/C/D for 25/6/2013 , not A/B ?

Comment: i need the employees who r not  allocated for a particular date

Answer (score 0):

Use group joing to get allocations of each employee. Then select those employees, which don't have any allocations for particular date:

```
from e in db.Employees
join ea in db.EmployeeAllocations 
   on e.ID equals ea.ID into g
where !g.Any(x => x.Date == date)
select e
```

Comment: hi this is not i expected .the above query returns all the employees who have already been allocated for a date..i need all the employees who hav enot be allocated for date

Answer (score 0):

[101 Linq](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) is a good reference site and [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9) seems most appropriate to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with repositories and want a less query like approach you could use the following:

```
IQueryable<int> allocatedEmployeeIds = AllocationRepository.DbSet.Where(x => x.Date == referenceDate).Select(x => x.ID);
List<Employee> allocatedEmployees = EmployeeRepository.DbSet.Where(x => allocatedEmployeeIds.Any(y => y == x.ID).ToList();
```

Edit: and if you want those not allocated it is just a matter of adding  "!"

```
IQueryable<int> allocatedEmployeeIds = AllocationRepository.DbSet.Where(x => x.Date == referenceDate).Select(x => x.ID);
List<Employee> allocatedEmployees = EmployeeRepository.DbSet.Where(x => !allocatedEmployeeIds.Any(y => y == x.ID).ToList();
```